# Automatic text changes via inheriting from another website

Tags: html, css, curl

I have a restaurant website with a html text section that i would like to automate the changes from our booking site.

I was thinking about maybe an API, but the booking site didnt have this.
There must be another way to do this.

Keep in mind, i have no extensive knowledge in this area, so if anyone wants to help me, try to keep it on a beginner level.

I have seen people do this with cURL, but i dont know where to even start.
**I have full access to backend of the site.**

**My website url: https://naturaj.se/fredagskassen**

*(Here under the title "Fredagskassen" there is menu, this is the section that should inherit from the booking page.)*

**This is the booking site url: https://naturaj.dinesuperb.com/reserve/experience**

*(The section called "Fredagskassen" and the menu underneath is the text section i would like to inherit to my website)*

So in short: Inherit html text section from another website.

*Other information:
The website is build in Wordpress with Elementor.*

**What ive tried so far:**
As my experience is very little, i havent tried anything specific.
I have read as much as i can on the issue. To try to find a easy way to do it but with no success. That is why im trying here.

Comment: What have you tried so far, please update that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an iframe?

```
<iframe src="https://naturaj.dinesuperb.com/reserve/experience"></iframe>
```